# Why Julia’s `Distributed.interrupt` terminates workers?

Tags: julia, distributed

I’m confused what the function [`Distributed.interrupt()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Distributed/#Distributed.interrupt) does. Documentation says it will ‘interrupt the current executing task on the specified workers’ but it seems to terminate the workers as well.

Example:

```
using Distributed

addprocs(1)  # Adding one local worker 
my_worker = workers()[1]

# Check number of processes
println("Processes: ", nprocs())

# Define a function
@everywhere function just_sleep(time)
    println("Sleeping...")
    sleep(time)
end

# Execute on the worker
remote_do(just_sleep, my_worker, 100)

# Wait a bit and interrupt
sleep(5)
interrupt(my_worker)

# Check number of processes again
sleep(5)
println("Processes: ", nprocs())
```

I get this output

```
> julia testing.jl
Processes: 2
      From worker 2:    Sleeping...
Worker 2 terminated.
Processes: 1
```

I’m expecting to have the worker process #2 still alive and number of processes still two at the end. It does not even help adding exception handling to the body of `just_sleep()`:

```
function just_sleep(time)
    println("Sleeping...")
    try
        sleep(time)
    catch e
        if isa(e, InterruptException)
            println("interrupted")
        else
            println(e)
        end
    end
end
```

Now `interrupt()` seems to behave like `Distributed.rmprocs()`. I have Julia 1.5.3 on Windows 10.

---

**EDIT**

I tried it also on WSL Ubuntu as well. There is a bit more info, but the worker also gets terminated

```
Processes: 2
      From worker 2:    Sleeping...
      From worker 2:    fatal: error thrown and no exception handler available.
      From worker 2:    InterruptException()
      From worker 2:    jl_mutex_unlock at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/locks.h:144 [inlined]
      From worker 2:    jl_task_get_next at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/partr.c:476
      From worker 2:    poptask at ./task.jl:704
      From worker 2:    wait at ./task.jl:712 [inlined]
      From worker 2:    task_done_hook at ./task.jl:442
      From worker 2:    _jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2214 [inlined]
      From worker 2:    jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2398
      From worker 2:    jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1690 [inlined]
Worker 2 terminated.      From worker 2:        jl_finish_task at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/task.c:196

      From worker 2:    start_task at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/task.c:715
      From worker 2:    unknown function (ip: (nil))
Processes: 1
```

Interestingly, it works on an interactive REPL session (only on Linux):

```
Processes: 2
workers() = [2]
      From worker 2:    Sleeping for 100 s...
      From worker 2:    interrupted!
Processes: 2
workers() = [2]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my system. Do you have an up-to-date Julia version?

Comment: I had Julia 1.4.2 and now installed 1.5.3, but I get the same result. I’m on Windows, could it be OS specific? What output do you get? What’s your system?

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu as well – and it does behave differently! A bug in the Windows implementation?

Comment: You might want to file an issue with Julia, then...

Comment: Oh, this is strange. I cannot even reproduce what I got on WSL Ubuntu anymore... What was the output you got @FrançoisFévotte?

Comment: `From worker 2:    InterruptException:`, then `Processes: 2`

Comment: Are you on Linux etc?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Debian, with Julia 1.5.3.

Comment: It works for me on a REPL session on Linux (see edit above). Did you get it working on the command line as well? @FrançoisFévotte

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce your findings on my system: your MWE works from the REPL and fails when called non-interactively. I think you should definitely file an issue on github, since this looks like it is a bug

Comment: Isn't the issue just that Windows doesn't support signals, so we basically send a `SIGKILL` instead of a `SIGINT`?

Comment: Maybe, but that does not explain the difference between command line and REPL behaviour on Linux. I added [`Base.exit_on_sigint(false)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/c/#Base.exit_on_sigint) to the function executed on the worker, but it does not help.